# SQL Trigger not on rows but on attributes

Tags: mysql

Hey guys a little question for you. 
I'm currently working on SQL Triggers and my goal is to archive logging if there are changes made to our database. For example we got some tables like customers with: name, firstname, placeofbirth and so on. We offer the users to update their own data and want to save the OLD data in a new table for logging reasons. To have only one logging table for all updates the logging table is kind of generic with: 
id, timestamp, table_name, column, old_value, new_value.

table_name is the updated table, colum the updated column in this table and all the rest should speak for itself. Therefore it would be great to know not only in which tuple but also in which particular column the update has happened. 
My question: Is there a construct like:

`create trigger logging_trigger on customer**.firstname** after insert` ...

to trigger an action only if there happened an update on let's say the 'firstname' column? 
If not is there a smooth solution for handling all possible update cases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a format like you described in my system... Below is how I accomplish it with your required logic.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `testing_schema`.`new_table_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `new_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.ColumnName <> OLD.ColumnName THEN
        INSERT INTO HistoryTable (`ColumnName1`, `ColumnName2`, ect..) VALUES (OLD.ColumnName1, OLD.ColumnName2, ect...); 
    END IF;
END
```

The main difference In mine is, that I do not have an IF condition.  I simply copy the entire row to the history table every time an Update/Delete is made to that row.  That way I don't have to maintain any form of logic to handle scenarios of investigating "what changed",  I just save the entire row because I know "something" changed.

Comment: Thanks for your share. That was how i did it firsthand as well i just wondered if there was and improved version to it. But i think i can work with that.

Comment: It has proven to be the most workable for me.. as long as you setup a Foreign key in the History table pointed at the UID in the primary table, you will maintain consistency and of course have an index.  So lookup is fast.  not to mention the added benefit of keeping your working Primary table small and quick instead of the other method of, keeping history in the primary table, just adding a Revision column or what not.  Good luck